# How to align a button corresponding to the background image for multiple screens?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am very new to this forum and really need help in something I got stuck in during developing the app.

This is the image I am using as my background (I named it SampleBG in xml):
https://i.gyazo.com/946507c2690c8170b54a1ace752906bd.png

Basically, this is what I want my design to look like:
https://i.gyazo.com/896e29846dfd9e4bc9ab15ca39f9a796.png

And for smaller devices, it automatically resizes and looks like this:
[i.gyazo.com/f4278339cc8f246187c011474796a12c.png]

And when I switch to a tablet device, it automatically looks like this:
[i.gyazo.com/1b0e233a0b1731148664e0ac78a05f08.png]

And the above is exactly what I want it to look like. The wooden signs are in the same position for all sizes...

**But the problem is:**
I want the wooden signs to be clickable, because they are meant to be buttons.

So, I tried to use a button widget and made it transparent and placed it over the wooden signs... it worked but it only worked for that particular size I designed it for (designed it for Nexus 5 to be specific).... However, when I switched to the Nexus One layout, or Nexus 9 layout, etc, the buttons weren't placed correctly over the wooden signs and thus didn't work.

I want a way to make the wooden signs clickable and and the buttons to be fixed with the signs for all device sizes/etc, and at the same time.

I would prefer an xml solution but a programmatic solution is nice too.

Here's the layout code right now, it just using the background image right now....

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sampleBG">

</RelativeLayout>`
```

NOTE:
I have tried using the door image as the background only and then adding the wooden signs manually by using the ImageButton widgets, but the wooden signs were being placed differently for different screens and it looked odd, so therefore I fixed the wooden signs with the background (in Photoshop).. now I just want the signs to be clickable.

Comment: Post your layout code.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sampleBG">

</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: One thing you could do is to slice your background image so you have the buttons as separate images. Then you can create your `Android` layout with 3 buttons and assign the images you sliced to the buttons as background. This means that you need to have your background image and the sliced buttons in 5 different resolutions as per guidelines, so they match the `hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi` sizes. That way android is going to pick the right sizes depending on the size of the device. You can also use a `RelativeLayout` to align the widgets.

Comment: Make your image as slice and make a part of it. Use `background image` that is only of  `wooden`  you have. Make slice of those 3 `Buttons` and add it as a `Background`.

Comment: @Apostrofix So, I need to have a hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, etc of this image? https://i.gyazo.com/5ed3f97b08b71237e6e731cbd12688bf.png

And by doing that. will it automatically place itself in the correct position for all devices... I prefer to design on the Nexus 4 layout, so if I designed for Nexus 4 layout, would it also automatically adjust its position for other devices?

Comment: @FormulatorX Yes, that's right. Just make sure to slice it properly - with transparent background and slice it by the edges of the image, so that it will be shown properly later in the app.

Comment: I will get the width and height % where the buttons should be positioned from the image, then position exactly there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample code that you can use, in order to achieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.test.androidtestapp.MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/equationsButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/equationsOfTheWeekButton"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="Equations Button"
        android:onClick="equationsButtonClick" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/equationsOfTheWeekButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="Equations Of The Week Button"
        android:onClick="equationsOfTheWeekButtonClick" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/equationsOfTheWeekButton"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="Settings Button"
        android:onClick="SettingsButtonClick" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You need to slice your image and then just change the `background` attributes in the code above. When you achieve that, you can change the background to a selector where you can change the image depending on the different states -> when it's clicked, focused, normal; that would make it more user friendly.

Comment: Hey, I know resolution for background images, but what would the resolution be for a button?

My wooden sign image is 406x380 by default... what would I resize it to for hdpi, mdpi, etc

Comment: @FormulatorX I recommend you to have a look at this article: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html It gives a very good overview.

Answer (score 0):

The wooden signs should NOT be on the background image.

Instead, make a real background image (ie. with only the "door" background) and make separate images with the signs.
Then use these images to build your buttons.

Edit: I did read your note about the fact that you tried that, but you should definitively go this way. Another advantage is that you'll be able to easily make the buttons reacting to the user click, with "onPress" states, which would be impossible (or at least difficult and ugly) with a single background image.

Comment: Okay, thankfully I have the wooden signs  and door as separate images already.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate wood pics that you want to be button and give them as a background for buttons. For example, you named the wooden pics as 'wood1.png' , 'wood2.png' and 'wood3.png' and by this sample code you can set them for background image for buttons :

```
<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/wood1"
  />
```

Or you can design your app by your own solution that described but you should create your app design by different layout for different size device :
layout-large
layout-small
layout-normal
layout-xlarge
layout-xxlarge

you can search about autoLayout design in android app and find your solution better..